# How to keep aspect ratio from image with animation in a div with container?

Tags: html, css

I didn't thought that would be as hard :-)

I would like to keep the aspect ratio of the image always right. Can't get the solution???

```css
.img-container {
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360);
  background-size: 110% 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: shrink 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
  }

  100% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="top">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would animate `scale()` rather than `background-size`. The animation will be much smoother.

```css
.img-container {
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360);
  background-size: 110% 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: shrink 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="top">
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <h1>Automated condition monitoring</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
```

If you want to prevent the image being stretched, use `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;`

```css
.img-container {
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: shrink 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container" id="top">
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <h1>Automated condition monitoring</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
```